# Manually Annotate on Chartjs React Graph and Save Annotation Data to Annotation Bar?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is there a way to manually annotate a chartjs react graph and save the data contents (i.e. the x timestamp values) of the manually annotated part to a annotation bar? This could be a boxed annotation or point annotation - whatever does the job for manual annotations.
This is for a project to create a eeg reader that can manually annotate a chartjs react graph for seizure detection.

I have tried looking online for information about manual annotations by chartjs, but have found nothing to help me thus far.
Apologies if this question is simple - I am very new to js.

Thanks!

[annotate this part and save to annotation bar for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daq3W.png)

Comment: There isn't a simple solution to your problem. You could manage chart.js's [interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#interactions),  possibly combine with [chartjs-plugin-annotations](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/). Consider sharing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your first attempts at a solution to  make your question interesting enough for someone out here to pick it up and help you out towards a working solution.

Comment: Thanks kikon, will see if I can accomplish a minimal reproducible example.